# How can I log into digital Ocean droplets using username and password, I want to deploy a MERN app

Tags: digital-ocean, webdeploy, mern, droplet

I'm used to using Putty to generate SSH KEY and logging in using my privatekey and passphrase. Now am working on a project and the owner generated a droplet password and username themselves.
I'm very confused now, I don't know how to log in to droplets using the password given to me.

What I have tried:
I have tried running `ssh root@<password>` but it didn't work.

This is the error I got:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <password>: Name or service not known
```

Your effort will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ssh <username>@<server>` (for example `ssh root@203.0.113.0`). You should then be prompted for the password. Enter the password (nothing will show while you type) then press enter.